# MVC 2 Beta 2 - TempData Bug?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

ASP.Net MVC 2 Beta -

I am aware there are some changes to TempData in MVC 2 Beta.

When trying to use TempData if the key name get/set have different case sensitivity, then the key doesn't seem to get destroyed.

e.g.

in Controller

```
TempData["Message"] = message;
```

in View

```
<% = TempData["message"]%>
```

My view will is play the value in message, but it never gets destroyed. So if I redirect elsewhere it sticks around. I don't believe case sensitivity was an issue in MVC 1?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug.  I've filed a work item in our tracking database.  Thanks for the report.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I guess because it doesn't care about case when you set the tempdata value, you could view it as a bug.

E.g. if you do:

```
TempData["Message"] = "Capital";
TempData["message"] = "Lower case";
```

Then access `TempData["Message"]` - it will equal `Lower case`.

So yeah, you could view it as a bug.

To avoid anything like that, I like to have a set of constants that I use to get and set ViewData and TempData values.

E.g.

```
public static class ViewDataKeys
{
    public const string HeadTitle = "HeadTitle";
    public const string PageTitle = "PageTitle";
    public const string FirstLevelMenuKey = "FirstLevelMenu";
    public const string SecondLevelMenuKey = "SecondLevelMenu";
    ... etc ...
}
```

HTHs,
Charles